# Drawable.SetTintList() behaving differently than View.BackgroundTintList (setBackgroundTintList()) [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

If the following `TextView`, *tinted_tv*, is tinted with `SetTintList()` (**option 1**), the property `BackgroundTintList` remains *null* (even when evaluated in a UI posted runnable).

However, when tinted with `BackgroundTintList` (`setBackgroundTintList()`) (**option 2**), it (`getBackgroundTintList()`) does not.

**Both options work as expected, so I'm not sure what the significance of their difference is, or the better one to use?**

**Layout**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tinted_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:background="@color/white"
/>
```

**Code**

```
TextView tv = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tinted_tv);

// option 1
tv.Background.SetTintList(Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.color_state_list));

// option 2
tv.BackgroundTintList = Context.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.color_state_list);
```

According to the [**Android.Views.View.BackgroundTintList Property**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.BackgroundTintList/) documentation

> **Get method documentation**[Android Documentation]
>   Return the tint applied to the background drawable, if specified.
>
> **Set method documentation**[Android Documentation]
>   Applies a tint to the background drawable. Does not modify the current tint mode, which is PorterDuff+Mode by default. Subsequent calls to View.Background will automatically mutate the drawable and apply the specified tint and tint mode using Drawable.SetTintList(ColorStateList).

I would imagine that the Xamarin `BackgroundTintList` property getter/setter corresponds to Android's `get`/`setBackgroundTintList()` `View` methods. **Does "raw" Android exhibit this same behavior (`getBackgroundTintList()` returns *null* following a call to `setBackgroundTintList()`)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`View.BackgroundTintList` is managed by the `View` and the tint is applied to the `View.Background` drawable when you call it. It's a layer of abstraction.

When you work directly with `Drawable.TintList` nobody knows or cares about it. That's why `View.BackgroundTintList` value remains unaffected.

`View.BackgroundTintList` has no precedence over `View.Background.SetTintList`. Whichever you call last wins.

On second look, there *is* one difference best described by a snippet from `View` source:

```
private void applyBackgroundTint() {
    if (mBackground != null && mBackgroundTint != null) {
        final TintInfo tintInfo = mBackgroundTint;
        if (tintInfo.mHasTintList || tintInfo.mHasTintMode) {
            mBackground = mBackground.mutate();

            if (tintInfo.mHasTintList) {
                mBackground.setTintList(tintInfo.mTintList);
            }

            if (tintInfo.mHasTintMode) {
                mBackground.setTintMode(tintInfo.mTintMode);
            }

            // The drawable (or one of its children) may not have been
            // stateful before applying the tint, so let's try again.
            if (mBackground.isStateful()) {
                mBackground.setState(getDrawableState());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Background drawable state is updated to state of view when you set `View.BackgroundTintList`, which is why you should choose this method when working with views.

When view state changes later background drawable state is updated regardless of which method you chose.

---

On top of `View.BackgroundTintList` there's also `View.BackgroundTintMode` which mirrors drawable API. Both of these values can be set by attributes in layout XML, something you can't do with standalone drawables. This approach may actually be used by the platform widgets.